# how to use Windows NT logon credentials in java swing application for user Authentication?

Tags: java, windows, swing

how to use Windows NT logon credentials in java swing application for user Authentication?

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used [jcifs](https://www.jcifs.org/) in the past to login using Windows NT credentials from Java apps.

Comment: Thanks Michael but can you please throw some more light on this..i am new to Swing... i have used com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem to obtain the username but how to check the password..kindly help..
Regards
Krishna

Comment: Actually what i have is not an web based application but it is a java desktop application

Comment: jcifs finally worked.....i just needed to check logged on user that i got from NTSystem and then it was all jcifs...thanks Michael for the help...:)

Comment: @krishna kumar, I want to achieve the same, can you, please, share how you did it?